# Java's relative path in class File

Tags: java, file, path

here is my code:

```
File file1 = new File("");
System.out.println(file1.exists()); // why the output is false?
System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());

// assume that my current path is "d:/xxx/yyy"
File file2 = new File(".");
System.out.println(file2.getPath());   // i want to get ""
                                       // but i actually get ".", 
                                       // which is not i want.
                                       // so how can i get ""
```

to sum up, what i want is an object file of class File, which when i call
file.getPath() it returns ""
and when i call file.exists() it returns true;

Comment: "" simply is not a valid file or path name. What do you really want to achieve with your code? Currently you only describe how you want to achieve something.

Comment: i surpose that the code "File file1 = new File("")" would create a File object which represents the current path. but it does not work as i think since "file1.exists()" returns false. and "new File(".")" create a File object which represents the current path, but the path contains ".", which i do not need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want to have the current working directory in a string, you can simply use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, see [System Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Otherwise you'll have to use `.` for the "current working directory" and use [File#getCanonicalPath()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) the get the canonical representation of this `File` object. Also see [File#getCanonicalFile()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

To your first question: `File("")` is a valid path and is equivalent to `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. It is not a valid file or directory in that path (it still doea have a path though. This is a completely relative path, so when you call `getPath()` it will return an empty string since no file found by the name "".

Your second question "." is a directory, it exists, and it also has a relative path of "", so when calling getPath you will see the path "" + the directory name "."